# Problems with GetOpenFileName()

Tags: c++, winapi, visual-c++

I'm having problems with the following code:

```
HANDLE hFile;
DWORD bytesRead;
OPENFILENAME ofn;
DWORD problem;
WCHAR title[260];

ZeroMemory(&ofn, sizeof(ofn));
ofn.lStructSize = sizeof(OPENFILENAME);
ofn.hwndOwner = hWnd;
ofn.lpstrFile = (LPWSTR)title;
ofn.nMaxFile = sizeof(title);
ofn.lpstrFilter = TEXT("All files(*.*)\0*.*\0");
ofn.nFilterIndex = 1;
ofn.lpstrInitialDir = NULL;
ofn.Flags = OFN_PATHMUSTEXIST | OFN_FILEMUSTEXIST;

if (GetOpenFileName(&ofn) == false)
{
    problem = CommDlgExtendedError();
    return false;
}
```

From GetOpenFileName it simply goes to `problem = CommDlgExtendedError();` without putting up a dialog.

Comment: ...and what exactly does it turn up as `problem`? BTW: Using C-style casts is just asking for trouble here.

Comment: It does not put up a window with the list of files.

Comment: So much was clear. What is in the `problem` variable (or whatever is used to further specify errors) afterwards was my question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to allocate a memory for the `lpstrFile` struct member and set `nMaxFile` to its size. Also first character of the buffer should be set to `\0` to prevent file name initialization. MSDN example:

```
// Initialize OPENFILENAME
ZeroMemory(&ofn, sizeof(ofn));
ofn.lStructSize = sizeof(ofn);
ofn.hwndOwner = hwnd;
ofn.lpstrFile = szFile;
// Set lpstrFile[0] to '\0' so that GetOpenFileName does not 
// use the contents of szFile to initialize itself.
ofn.lpstrFile[0] = '\0';
```